# get data using webservice android

Tags: android, json

I have data on a server which stores name and images.
I want to retrieve that from server and display in table layout on Android.

I wonder which is the best xmlparsing or json parsing for that purpose.
Is there any tutorial for that?

```
if($_REQUEST['mode']=="get")
{
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT state,imageurl FROM `pic_upload`");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
                $output=$row;

                print(json_encode($output));

        }
        mysql_close;
 }
```

using this i will get data from server but how to get data using xml parsing any one know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `json_encode($output)` will produce a JSON output, so you should use Android's JSON API (org.json).

A quite recent tutorial is located at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ (also showing how to put retrieved elements on a list), but you will find many simply googling for Android and JSON.

Comment: hey when i run my webservice is show me data which is not proper formatted <http://mybackofficework.com/carpark/car_parking/pictastik/image.php?mode=get

Comment: we can chek our json format using this website just copy our result and paste on this site and you get the format is valid or not <http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: after copy in Text Click on View so u get the result but in my data is give me invalid json variable

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple item and no huge list, the `org.json` packages that come with Android are perfect.

Have a look at that [Tutorial from Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) to get started.